# (Ionic 4) Can't receive notification with firebaseX when app is in foreground

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, notifications, foreground

I use FirebaseX to receive notification in my application.
I correctly receive notification in the background. But when the app is in the foreground, nothing happens...

I have searched for this problem, but nothing works for me. 
I have try to had the following data in the data content (when server call url to send notification)
 [notification_foreground] => true
 [tap] => true

Here is my plugin list :

```
cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter 1.1.0 "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter"
cordova-plugin-app-version 0.1.9 "AppVersion"
cordova-plugin-badge 0.8.8 "Badge"
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.3 "Device"
cordova-plugin-dialogs 2.0.2 "Notification"
cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated 3.0.0 "Cordova FCM Push Plugin"
cordova-plugin-file 6.0.2 "File"
cordova-plugin-firebasex 5.0.0 "Google Firebase Plugin"
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.1 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-local-notification 0.9.0-beta.2 "LocalNotification"
cordova-plugin-speechrecognition 1.1.2 "Speech Recognition"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.3 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.3 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.4 "Whitelist"
```

ionic info:

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 5.2.8 
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.9.0
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.13.9
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.3.9
   @angular/cli                  : 7.3.9
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.5.1

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.0.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.1, (and 23 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.5.1
   native-run  : 0.2.7

System:

   NodeJS : v10.16.0 
   npm    : 6.10.1
   OS     : Windows 10
```

the code to subscribre to the message...

```
this.firebase.onMessageReceived().subscribe(notification => {
            console.log('NOTIFICATION !!!!');
            console.log(notification);
            alert( JSON.stringify(notification) );
            if (notification['tap']) {
                this.navCtrl.navigateRoot('/test');
            } else {
                alert( JSON.stringify(notification) );
            }
        });
```

When the app is in the background, I receive the notification and when I tap on it, I have the alert message and console log.

But when the app is in the foreground, nothing is displayed.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With --prod it seem to work without doing nothing else... 
it's in debug mode that is not working

Answer (score 1):

**cordova-plugin-firebasex** plugin isn't working with **cordova-plugin-local-notification** plugin I have already faced this issue into my current ionic ios application but with the android, it's working perfectly

According to @dpa99c

The problem is that both this plugin and cordova-plugin-local-notifications implements the same UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate willPresentNotification delegate and since delegates have a 1:1 relationship with their parent class, only one of the delegates is being called - in this case, the cordova-plugin-firebasex delegate in response to the notification created by cordova-plugin-local-notifications.

Please check the below link for the details description

https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebasex/issues/230

**Solution:**
Please use [this](https://github.com/Steffaan/cordova-plugin-local-notifications) local notification plugin with **cordova-plugin-firebasex** It's working perfectly in android and iOS both platform

Answer (score 0):

From https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebasex#background-notifications

If the notification message arrives while the app is in running in the foreground, **by default it will NOT be displayed as a system notification**. Instead the notification message payload will be passed to the onMessageReceived callback for the plugin to handle (tap will not be set).

If you include the notification_foreground key in the data payload, the plugin will also display a system notification upon receiving the notification messages while the app is running in the foreground. For example:

{
  "name": "my_notification",
  "notification": {
    "body": "Notification body",
    "title": "Notification title"
  },
  "data": {
    "notification_foreground": "true",
  }
}

.Maigais

Answer (score 0):

it's not about prod or QA or Debug Mode. For foreground messages to trigger you need to incorporate "notification_foreground": "true" under data Object in Notification Payload.

Example:

```
{
 "to" : "your device token",
 "notification" :{
     "body" : "your message body",
     "title": "your title for notification"
 },
  "data":{
       "notification_foreground": "true"
  }
 }
```